# Saving hashmap to mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a schema like so

```
var csData = new Schema({
    csgo_number: Number,
    last_updated: Number,
    items: {type: Object, default: {}}

}, { minimize: false });
```

Due to items being a large list I decided to make it a hash map to access it faster.

```
items:{
    item1: {
        price: 2.00
    },
    item2:{
        price: 1.00
    },
    item3:{
        price: 3.00
    }
}
```

I'm looping through a bunch of html i'm parsing and storing each new item when I come across it.

```
var item1 = 'awp'
csData.findOne({"csgo_number": 1}, function(err, csgoDB){
    csgoDB.items[item1] = {
        price: 2.00
    }


    csgoDB.save(function(err){
        if(err){console.log('something went wrong')}
    });
});
```

Even though I get no error. My data doesn't save. Is this because I don't have a _id for my new item? I tried it with an _id and it still didn't save.

Comment: try using `items: {type: Schema.Types.Mixed, default: {}}`

Comment: Yeah this worked. I also needed to add items.markModified before I saved

Answer (score 6):

Since mongoose 5.1.0 there's a new type, [**Map**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#maps). Wich does that:

```js
var csData = new Schema({
    csgo_number: Number,
    last_updated: Number,
    items: {
        type: Map,
        of: String,
        default: {}
    }
}, { minimize: false });
```

To use it, just:

```js
var item1 = 'awp'
csData.findOne({"csgo_number": 1}, function(err, csgoDB){
    csgoDB.items.set('item1.price', 2.00);

    csgoDB.save(function(err){
        if(err){console.log('something went wrong')}
    });
});
```

And to fetch it:

```js
var item1 = 'awp'
csData.findOne({"csgo_number": 1}, function(err, csgoDB){
    var value = csgoDB.items.get('item1.price');
});
```